# R Tmap - openstreet layer under tm_shape polygons

Tags: r, tmap

I have the below R code that plots two layers on a static map using TMAP. Firstly, there is a layer which draws polygons of the area of interest. On top of this, there are some dots plotted that show sales locations.

What I would like to do is have the base layer be from something like openstreetmap rather than shaded a single color from tm_fill. I would, however, also like to retain the polygon structure and have the areas outside of the polygons of interest to be white, rather than having the whole openstreetmap layer visible (e.g. everything outside of the polygons is 'masked' white, everything within the polygons has the openstreetmap layer visible). Some guidance is below but I am unable to resolve, can anyone please help?

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tmap/versions/3.3-2/topics/tm_basemap
https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/

Currently used code:

```
#Plot via tm_shape
OutputMap <- tm_shape(PMSOAs) + 
  tm_fill(col = "lightgreen") +
  tm_borders(
    col = NA,
    lwd = 0.5,
    lty = "solid",
    alpha = NA,
    zindex = NA,
    group = NA
  ) +
tm_shape(SalesAddressLocations)+
  tm_dots(col = "red", size = 0.02) +
  tm_layout(title = 'Sales Locations, Date X - Date Y', title.size = 0.4, title.position = c("center", "top")) 

OutputMap
```

Comment: This book is a useful resource. I think chapter 9 might have the info you're looking for: https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/adv-map.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution. I used freely available postalcode data of Germany and focussed on postalcodes starting with 60 (area around Frankfurt):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)

# read postalcode shape file (data from https://www.suche-postleitzahl.org/downloads)
df_pc <- st_read(dsn = "data/plz-gebiete.shp/") %>%  
  as_tibble() %>% 
  filter(str_detect(plz, "^60")) %>% 
  st_as_sf

# generate 1) edge polygon unioning all postalcode geometries
# and 2) corresponding bounding box
df_pols <- st_union(df_pc) %>%  as_tibble() %>% 
 mutate(bbox = st_as_sfc(st_bbox(geometry))) %>% st_as_sf()

# compute difference between bounding box and edge polygon
diff_pol <- st_difference(df_pols$bbox, df_pols$geometry)

# read openstreetmap tile
osm <- read_osm(df_pc) 

# first plot osm content
tm_shape(osm) + 
  tm_rgb() +
# overlay difference polygon to mask content outside
tm_shape(diff_pol) +
  tm_fill(col = "white") +
# add postalcode polygons atop
tm_shape(df_pc) +
  tm_borders(lwd = 1.5, col = "darkblue") +
tm_layout(frame = F)
```

[image]